# How to group duplicates in second column and assign them a new number in a third column?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that looks like this

```
1, C10 C11 N3 O1
2, C19 C23 O2
3, C19 N2 O2
4, C10 C11 O1
5, C11 N3 O1
6, C13 C8 O3
7, C8 N5 O3
```

The first column is the group number and the second column is the items in that group. I want to search through the second column and see how many times one of the strings in the row matches any of the strings in the other rows. Then, I need to put a new number in the third column that corresponds to groups that have TWO OR MORE matches.

Example:

```
1, C10 C11 N3 O1
4, C10 C11 O1
5, C11 N3 O1
```

Groups 1, 4, and 5 all have two or more strings that match. Therefore, they would all get assigned to a new groups like so:

```
1, C10 C11 N3 O1, 1
4, C10 C11 O1, 1
5, C11 N3 O1, 1
```

I am new to this and stumped. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
I'm trying to have my code something like this, but I can't get it to work.

```
while read -r line; do 
     awk '$1 !=$1 && $2 == $2 {print $0}'
done
```

If another row belongs to two groups, then I would just put it with the first corresponding group. That info won't matter too much, as long as it is in with a matching group. Preferably, the group would encompass all 2+ matching strings though.

Comment: what do you do when you have overlaps and an entry belongs to 2 new groups, eg: `1, C1 C2 C3 C4`, `2, C1 C2` and `3, C3 C4` ... in this case `1, C1 C2 C3 C4` belongs to 2 new groups

Comment: @markp-fuso Preferably, I would put all three of those matching the same group. If that is too hard to do though, I would read and put the first group in one and the second row that doesn't match in another group

Comment: Hi Hailey, you can see that Fravadona and I are not in agreement as to what the output should be.  I suggest that in order to get the best results on this thread, you should provide complete desired output.  IMHO, the requirements leave a bit to the discretion of the implementor - and this is definitely the reason why you have answers with different results (respectfully).

Comment: @Mark putting aside the renumbering of the groups, the main difference in our  implementations is that I assign each entry to a group that contains its best match (of two or more matches).

Comment: @Fravadona - thanks for the eight entry example in your post.  I see what you are talking about and how our algorithms diverge.  I  assign items to the first match and you are assigning to the best match.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python answer that may be helpful.  I can explain the logic so that it can be coded in awk if you wish:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import collections

groups = {}
items_in_groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for line in f:
    group_num,items = line.split(",")
    if items:
      groups[ group_num ] = items.split()
      for item in groups[ group_num ]: 
        items_in_groups[ item ].append(group_num)

for group,items in groups.items():
  for item in items:
    if len( items_in_groups[ item ] ) >= 2: 
      print( f'{group},{" ".join(items)},{items_in_groups[ item ][0]}' )
      break
  else:
      print( f'{group},{" ".join(items)},N/A' )
```

The above code (seems like there is a lot, doesn't it?) produces the following output:

```
1 , C10 C11 N3 O1 , 1
2 , C19 C23 O2 , 2
3 , C19 N2 O2 , 2
4 , C10 C11 O1 , 1
5 , C11 N3 O1 , 1
6 , C13 C8 O3 , 6
7 , C8 N5 O3 , 6
```

Essentially, I'm doing a double pass through your data.  The first pass, we are reading the data into a very simple associative array (well, dict in python) called groups.   groups maps the group number to a list of items (e.g. 3 --> C19,N2,02 ).  Here's the group dict after it is populated:

Group:

```
{'1': ['C10', 'C11', 'N3', 'O1'], '2': ['C19', 'C23', 'O2'], '3': ['C19', 'N2', 'O2'], '4': ['C10', 'C11', 'O1'], '5': ['C11', 'N3', 'O1'], '6': ['C13', 'C8', 'O3'], '7': ['C8', 'N5', 'O3']}
```

items_in_groups:

```
{'C10': ['1', '4'], 'C11': ['1', '4', '5'], 'N3': ['1', '5'], 'O1': ['1', '4', '5'], 'C19': ['2', '3'], 'C23': ['2'], 'O2': ['2', '3'], 'N2': ['3'], 'C13': ['6'], 'C8': ['6', '7'], 'O3': ['6', '7'], 'N5': ['7']}
```

items_in_groups is also created on the first pass of the data - for every item we find, we add the group we found it in to an associated list.  For instance, we found 'C10' in both group 1 and group 4.

Finally, with items_in_groups computed, we can look for the matches of 2 or more.  We loop through the groups (in the order they were read from the file - in recent versions of python the dict ordering is preserved).  Then, we loop through each item in that group, checking to see if that item appears in more than one group.  If we find an item that appears in more than one group, we stop, printing out the current group, it's items, and the first group in list of matching groups.

EDIT:  Simplified the code - the reading of the input file is done line by line now and the print statements at the end are easier to read.  Lastly, added a bit of code to handle the situation of no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer, but this time written in awk.  I basically did a translation from python to awk.

```
awk -F, '
{ # first pass 
  groups[ $1 ] =  $2
  split( $2, items, " " ) 
  for (item in items) {
    items_in_groups[ items[item] ] = items_in_groups[ items[item] ] " " $1
  }
}
END {  # second pass
  for ( group in groups ) {
    split( groups[group], items, " " ) 
    for ( item in items ) { 
      split( items_in_groups[ items[item] ] , in_groups, " " ) 
      if (length( in_groups ) >= 2)  {
        print group,groups[group],in_groups[1]
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
' $1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This and the python script both worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

`python`, `awk`, and now comes `ruby`.

The algorithm first index the data in associative arrays: one array for listing the items of a group, and another one for listing the groups that an item belongs to.

Then, for each group, it searches for his highest match among the groups that share at least one item with it (discarding the ones that only share one item with it).

Lastly, it will assign each group to the same group than his highest match, or start a new group if his highest match isn't assigned to any group at that moment.

This somewhat should fit your specs.

***edit:** removed the renumbering of the new groups in the code*

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# my naming sense sucks but it makes it easy to read the code below
items_of = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
groups_of = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

ARGF.each_line do |line|
  groupID,itemsStr = line.split(',')
  items_of[groupID] = itemsStr.split if itemsStr
  items_of[groupID].each {|itemID| groups_of[itemID] << groupID}
end

assigned_group_of = {}

items_of.each do |groupID,itemsArr|
  bestMatch = itemsArr.map { |itemID|
    groups_of[itemID]
  }.flatten.uniq.reject{ |gID|
    gID == groupID || (items_of[groupID] & items_of[gID]).count < 2
  }.max { |a,b|
    (items_of[groupID] & items_of[a]).count - (items_of[groupID] & items_of[b]).count
  }
  assigned_group_of[groupID] = bestMatch.nil? || assigned_group_of[bestMatch].nil? ? groupID : assigned_group_of[bestMatch]

  print "#{groupID}, #{items_of[groupID].join(' ')}, #{assigned_group_of[groupID]}\n"
```

***note:** the script accepts input from stdin, files or both at the same time (exactly like the `cat` command); ex. `cat file1 file2 file3 | script.rb` or `script.rb file1 file2 file3` or `cat file2 | script.rb file1 - file3`*

Output example:

***edit:** added an eight entry to show the difference in behavior with @Mark algorithm.*

```
1, C10 C11 N3 O1, 1
2, C19 C23 O2, 2
3, C19 N2 O2, 2
4, C10 C11 O1, 1
5, C11 N3 O1, 1
6, C13 C8 O3, 6
7, C8 N5 O3, 6
8, C10 C19 C23, 2
```

---

###### behavior to ponder with

Depending on the ordering of the entries, you can get different results:

```
1, A10 B10, 1
2, A10 B10 C20 D20, 1
3, C20 D20, 1
```

```
1, A10 B10, 1
2, C20 D20, 2
3, A10 B10 C20 D20, 1
```

---

###### Update for @Mark

More precisely, the ruby version of your code would be:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
groups = {}
items_in_groups = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

ARGF.each_line do |line|
  group_num,items = line.split(',')
  groups[ group_num ] = items.split() if items
  groups[ group_num ].each {|item| items_in_groups[ item ] << group_num}
end

groups.each do |group,items|
  item = items.find {|i| items_in_groups[ i ].count >=2}
  print "#{group}, #{items.join(' ')}, #{item.nil? ? "N/A" : items_in_groups[ item ][0]}\n"
end
```

Comment: Interesting to see the ruby version.  I see that you created new groups - You put groups 6 and 7 in a "new" group 3.  Whereas, my solution just used the pre-existing group 6.   I was hoping that @Hailey would look at the output and let us know whether that met the desired goal (but requirements in this case are hard to know).  Hailey should probably just provide the desired output for the example with an explanation.

Comment: See the code at the end of my post for the Ruby version of your code ;-)

Comment: You'll be pleased to know that the "behavior to ponder with" datasets yield consistent output when you run them through the "Update for @Mark" version.  I may have to learn ruby now! :)

Comment: Your algorithm does it right in my examples, but it has its own caveats: I added an eight line to OP's example that will show you why there's also a little problem with it. BTW, Ruby is nice but I don't think it's worth switching to Ruby if you already know Python well. In my case I switched from _occasional_ Perl to Ruby (that was a good choice IMO).